# Swift - `.framework` file is not generated

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks

So I just followed this very short [tutorial](https://medium.com/@PyBaig/build-your-own-cocoa-touch-frameworks-in-swift-d4ea3d1f9ca3#.qi8owqbel) on how to create a framework with Swift.
At one point, the author of the article does this:

[image]

This leads him to this:

[image]

When I try to do the same, nothing happens though (Finder is never opened). So I thought I could just manually navigate to the project's folder to find the `.framework` file. But it seems, that such a file is simply never generated:

[image]

And even after searching for `SortedList.framework` in Spotlight, nothing is found.

A noteworthy detail is also, that in Xcode, the 'Products' are shown in red:

[image]

Why is the `.framework` file not generating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework is being generated, but it is located within Xcode's `DerivedData` directory where your project is built, not the directory where your framework's source files are located.

Your target's path is likely not correct, which is why the product's name  appears in red, and Finder can't open a window to that directory.

The location for the framework should be `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework`, which (for the Debug configuration) would expand to:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SortedList-<random suffix>/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SortedList.framework`

**Update:**

If you select the framework product, then look in the Utilities -> File Inspector pane, you should see that its name is `SortedList.framework`, its type is `Framework`, and its location is `Relative to Build Products`.

The full path shown below that should automatically correspond to the DerivedData location for the framework.

Here's an example of what a framework's File Location pane would look like.

[image]

Comment: Ok. So, I did find the `.framework` file now, as you described.
What I don't know is: Where do I change my targets path. I never changed it, so I don't know how it could be incorrect. In other words: How do I get the product's name to stop being red :D ?

Comment: @MarcusRossel I've added details showing where you can update the product's File Information.

Comment: Yes, I saw that the path is shown. And it does correspont with the actual location of the `.framework` file. But why is Xcode unable to realize that, when trying to "Show In Finder"?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'm writing this here to build upon PetahChristian's excellent answer.

I had the same issue, my folder was listed in Xcode as:

/Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PDFManipulator-ggvfnlbpcgwblwdnvsnxweqnuvgc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PDFManipulatorTests.xctest

But in reality, it exists in:

/Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PDFManipulator-ggvfnlbpcgwblwdnvsnxweqnuvgc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PDFManipulatorTests.xctest

Notice that the last folder each is slightly different. I can rename reality to make it the same as the Xcode one which fixes the problem.

However, if I rebuild the project again the files are recreated in Debug-iphonesimulator. Not sure how to fix that.